Como resuelvo un error en python que se presenta en el BATCH de un entrenamiento de red neuronal recurrente
Red Neuronal Recurrente
El objetivo es generar nuevos nombres de dinosaurios , usando la data nombres_dinosaurios.txt que entrene la neurona sin presentar errores.
Este código está diseñado para entrenar una Red Neuronal Recurrente (RNN) simple usando Keras para generar nombres de dinosaurios. Aquí está el resumen de cómo funciona cada parte del código:

Lectura y Preprocesamiento de Datos
Lectura del Dataset:
El archivo nombres_dinosaurios.txt se lee y se convierte a minúsculas.

Construcción del Diccionario:
Se crea un diccionario de caracteres únicos presentes en el archivo para mapear cada carácter a un índice y viceversa.

Definición del Modelo
Arquitectura del Modelo:

Entrada (Input): La entrada del modelo tiene una forma (None, tam_alfabeto), donde None permite una secuencia de longitud variable.
Capa Recurrente (SimpleRNN): Se utiliza una capa RNN con activación tanh, que retorna el estado oculto.
Capa de Salida (Dense): La capa de salida es una capa densa con activación softmax que predice la probabilidad de cada carácter en el alfabeto.
Compilación del Modelo:
Se utiliza el optimizador SGD con una tasa de aprendizaje de 0.0005 y la función de pérdida es categorical_crossentropy.

Generación de Datos para el Entrenamiento
Generador de Datos:
Un generador produce secuencias de caracteres en formato one-hot y las desplaza para crear pares de entrada y salida. Este generador se utiliza para alimentar el modelo.

Dataset de TensorFlow:
Se crea un dataset de TensorFlow desde el generador para el entrenamiento del modelo.

Entrenamiento del Modelo
Entrenamiento:
El modelo se entrena durante NITS iteraciones, actualizando su peso y reportando el error cada 1000 iteraciones.
Generación de Nombres
Función de Generación:
La función generar_nombre utiliza el modelo entrenado para generar nombres secuenciales. Inicia con un estado oculto y un vector de entrada vacío, y predice el siguiente carácter en cada paso, actualizando el estado oculto y la entrada.
Problemas Encontrados
Error de Forma de Entrada:
Se está produciendo un error al pasar la entrada al modelo debido a una forma incorrecta. La forma esperada es (None, None, 27), pero se está proporcionando

El error se presenta en el entrenamiento de la red recurrente
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "functional" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, 27), found shape=(None, None, 1, 27)
El código es el siguiente
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, SimpleRNN
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Valores aleatorios
np.random.seed(5)

# 1. LECTURA DEL SET DE DATOS
nombres = open('nombres_dinosaurios.txt', 'r').read()
nombres = nombres.lower()

# Crear diccionario
alfabeto = list(set(nombres))
tam_datos, tam_alfabeto = len(nombres), len(alfabeto)
print("En total hay %d caracteres, y el diccionario tiene un tamaño de %d caracteres." % (tam_datos, tam_alfabeto))

car_a_ind = {car: ind for ind, car in enumerate(sorted(alfabeto))}
ind_a_car = {ind: car for ind, car in enumerate(sorted(alfabeto))}
print(car_a_ind)
print(ind_a_car)

# 2. MODELO - Creación de la Red recurrente
n_a = 25
entrada = Input(shape=(None, tam_alfabeto))
a0 = Input(shape=(n_a,))  # Estado oculto
celda_recurrente = SimpleRNN(n_a, activation='tanh', return_state=True)
capa_salida = Dense(tam_alfabeto, activation='softmax')
hs, _ = celda_recurrente(entrada, initial_state=a0)
salida = capa_salida(hs)

modelo = Model([entrada, a0], salida)
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.0005)
modelo.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# 3. EJEMPLOS DE ENTRENAMIENTO
def train_generator():
    while True:
        ejemplo = ejemplos[np.random.randint(0, len(ejemplos))]
        X = [None] + [car_a_ind[c] for c in ejemplo]
        Y = X[1:] + [car_a_ind['\n']]

        x = np.zeros((len(X), 1, tam_alfabeto))
        onehot = to_categorical(X[1:], tam_alfabeto).reshape(len(X) - 1, 1, tam_alfabeto)
        x[1:, :, :] = onehot
        y = to_categorical(Y, tam_alfabeto).reshape(len(X), tam_alfabeto)

        a = np.zeros((1, n_a))

        yield [x, a], y

# Crear un dataset desde el generador
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    train_generator,
    output_signature=(
        (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, tam_alfabeto), dtype=tf.float32),
         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, n_a), dtype=tf.float32)),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, tam_alfabeto), dtype=tf.float32)
    )
)

BATCH_SIZE = 80 #Error se genera al ejecutar este segmento de codigo
NITS = 10000

for j in range(NITS):
    historia = modelo.fit(dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE), steps_per_epoch=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=1, verbose=0)

    if j % 1000 == 0:
        print('\nIteración: %d, Error: %f' % (j, historia.history['loss'][0]) + '\n')

def generar_nombre(modelo, car_a_ind, tam_alfabeto, n_a):
    x = np.zeros((1, 1, tam_alfabeto))
    a = np.zeros((1, n_a))

    nombre_generado = ''
    fin_linea = '\n'
    car = -1

    while (car != fin_linea and len(nombre_generado) < 50):
        prediccion = modelo.predict([x, a], verbose=0)
        ix = np.random.choice(len(prediccion[0]), p=prediccion[0].ravel())

        car = ind_a_car[ix]
        nombre_generado += car

        x = to_categorical(ix, tam_alfabeto).reshape(1, 1, tam_alfabeto)
        a = prediccion[1]  # Utilizar el estado oculto actualizado

    print(nombre_generado)

# RESULTADO
print(generar_nombre(modelo, car_a_ind, tam_alfabeto, n_a))



Bienvenida al sitio, te invito a hacer el [tour]. En casos de errores con python, es buena idea que también incluyas en la pregunta el stack trace, que se imprime usualmente junto al mensaje de error. Dale clic en [edit] para agregarle. Un saludo.
